# Upgrade ClearDB from Bluemix without having to migrate

Tags: migration, ibm-cloud, instance, upgrade, cleardb

Is there any way to upgrade ClearDB plan from Bluemix. When I click on a better plan it creates a new ClearDB instance. I would like to upgrade without needing to migrate data to a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support upgrade in place for IBM Cloud ClearDB databases.  This is a roadmap item that will be implemented in the near future.  In the interim, you will need to deploy a new instance and use a tool like MySQL Workbench which has a convenient upgrade wizard to migrate your data to the new plan.  We recommend you place your application in maintenance mode during the migration.